# Android Images for various devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I have question regarding Android Layouts.I have read the documentation of [Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) .My question is that while developing lets say if the images are placed in the folders named

```
 drawable-hdpi
 drawable-ldpi
 drawable-mdpi
 drawable-xhdpi
```

Does drawable-ldpi refers to the phones with smaller screen ,drawable-xhdpi for tabs and drawable-mdpi medium sized screen phones.

If not i have a image i need to be able to put into all types of devices namingly phone,tab

How can i do  it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually, larger screens have higher DPIs, but that is not always the case. if you are trying to differentiate between phone and tablet screens, density is not the right way. use the following,

- `drawable`: phones
- `drawable-sw600dp`: 7" tablets
- `drawable-sw720dp`: 10" tablets

alternatively, you can use the screen size: `small`, `medium`, `large`, `xlarge`. e.g., `drawable-large`. from the docs,

- `xlarge` screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- `large` screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- `normal` screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- `small` screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

> http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Larger DPI screens ALWAYS have higher DPIs - I think you mean "Larger screens often have higher DPIs, but not necessarily"

Answer (score 1):

Googling `Android xhdpi` brings up the Android resource on how you should use these:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

DPI means how many dots per inch there are.  Some small phones fit lots of dots in, which gives them a high DPI.  You should provide different sized images for different resolutions.  Google recommends creating images in the ration of `3:4:6:8` for l, m, h and xh DPIs.